# I am looking to have an image in navbar change to a different when a corresponding section on the page is in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, intersection-observer

I have images in a navbar that change their src when the image hovered over using mouseover. I am looking to have that same hover effect on the image when a section is scrolled to in viewport that matches the id.

This is what I have attempted recently. The hover works fine, but the image doesn't seem to change when section is scrolled to.

One example in the navbar

```
<div class="number"><a href="#3"><img class="ai" src="https://unsplash.com/photos/Z1wosLgwGT8" onmouseover="this.src='https://unsplash.com/photos/q98u_gIRs6I'" onmouseout="this.src='https://unsplash.com/photos/Z1wosLgwGT8'" alt="3"></a></div>
```

One div example with the id to match navbar link

```
<div class="test" id="1">
<div class="test" id="2">
<div class="test" id="3">
<div class="test" id="4">
```

The JS I have so far

```
const testDiv = document.querySelector("#3");
    const aiImg = document.querySelector(".ai");

    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
      const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
      const divTop = testDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      const divBottom = testDiv.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
      
      if (divTop <= viewportHeight && divBottom >= 0) {
        aiImg.src = "https://unsplash.com/photos/q98u_gIRs6I";
      }
    });
```

Comment: Check the line with `aiImg.src = `. This should equal a pure URL, but you have an extraneous `"this.src='"` within, which is unnecessary and malformed.

Comment: Apologize that was an extra add by accident in this post. I have edited it match what it is currently.

Comment: Well I'd check if any scroll event itself can invokes an image swap, if so, then you know it's your if-statement inside the listener which is the problem.